# Mount existing 2-HDD RAID 0 on a new machine

Tags: raid-0

Last week, my graphics controllers burnt (after 7 years of loyal service), well, my laptop (Clevo x7200) is now out of usage.

On this laptop I have two disks mounted on a RAID 0.
Disks are OK and they work very well. I plugged them in an external USB RAID controller (GLOTRENDS 2.5" Dual Bay Enclosure), Windows detected that there are two disks (500Gb * 2 = 1Tb), but not initialized. I would like to retrieve data inside these two disks without breaking anything. Any idea to remount these two disks in order to retrieve data inside ?

**Edit from comments**:

- Hardware RAID from the integrated controller on motherboard.
- Stripe size = 128kb

Comment: What initiated the RAID 0? Software or hardware? If software, which program? If hardware, which controller?

Comment: "I do not know RAID details: Stripe size, disk order..." - This is vital information.  Typically you cannot just go moving RAID arrays between different hardware RAIDS controllers.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I edited my first post, I remembered the Stripe size.

Comment: The information you provided isn't specific enough.

Comment: What should I provide more? I am not a RAID specialist.

Comment: Can't you use the same motherboard that created it in the first place to get data off of it? RAID controllers are not universal. Each controller does things their own way so you can't just go from one to another expecting the other one to read it

Comment: Isn't it funny that your username here is Cloud Company but you don't know RAIDs? :D

Comment: Graphics is completely dead, even if I plug another screen, so I can't extract from them... And CloudCompany, it cames from FFVII ;)

Comment: What OS is there? Are you able to connect there over network (SSH/VNC/RDP)?

Comment: You need to find a similar (ideally identical) controller and put the disks in that.  When I say similar, I mean same make and RAID levels - ideally from another identical laptop, but you might get away with a different card that used the same chipset.  If it was using fakeraid you might be able to put disks in another PC with fakeraid - Using a USB raid is a bad idea as USB abstracts the hardware and often presents different drive geometries.

Comment: The problem is that RAID0 implementations are  proprietary. The easiest way to recover data is with an identical computer. Failing that it can be done with special software. I don't have any experience with such. Most free software doesn't do RAID0. This can be a challenge, even for a data recovery professional. You really should have backups of a RAID0 volume.

Comment: @JaroslavKucera This comment can be really helpful, I did not think about this. But my system boots on Windows without any VNC or RDP configurations. But for my new machine, I will set up it, thanks for this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, this was not so "impossible" to retrieve, even without "vital" informations...

As I said, my two disks are clean and 100% works. I re-put them in my USB RAID controller using JBOD configuration (in order to show to Windows two different disks).

First, I ran **ReclaiMe Free RAID Recovery** which retrieve my RAID configuration in a few minutes. Second, I used a recovery software which support RAID 0 configuration. It mounted a virtual NTFS partition of my two RAID 0 disks which can be fully explorable. So I retrieved all my user data.